# How to customize icons for conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to customize the icons criteria. I need 5 conditions. I used IconSetCondition.

Conditions are:

1. value < 0.85
2. value < 0.95
3. value < 1.06
4. value < 1.15
5. value >=1.15

I would like to use 3Traffic lights in this way:

1. value < 0.85 --> "red traffic light"
2. value < 0.95 --> "orange traffic light"
3. value < 1.06 --> "green traffic light"
4. value < 1.15 --> "orange traffic light"
5. value >=1.15 --> "red traffic light"

I voluntary used xl5Arrows to get the 5 conditions.

```
Set r = Range(Cells(3, 6), Cells(nbtopics + 2, 6))
With r
    With .FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .AddIconSetCondition
    End With
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .ReverseOrder = False
        .ShowIconOnly = False
        .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl5Arrows)
        With .IconCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0.85
            .Operator = xlGreater
        End With
        With .IconCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 0.95
            .Operator = xlGreater
        End With
        With .IconCriteria(4)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 1.05
            .Operator = xlGreater
        End With
        With .IconCriteria(5)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = 1.15
            .Operator = xlGreater
        End With
    End With
End With
```

This code works, however I would like `Traffic lights` instead of `xl5Arrows`.

Thank you very much for your help. If you need further details, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Hi Arthur, what I do to get the code is use the macro recorder, do what I need to and then fit it to my needs. Thought I guess you need to change this: `.IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl5Arrows)` some `xl5TrafficLights` or whatever, you'll find it yourself by doing the macro record.

Comment: There is no [`xl5TrafficLights`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xliconset?view=excel-pia) unfortunately.

Comment: True that, just checked and you can only have 4 (`xl4TrafficLights`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, vba doesn't recognize `xl5trafficlights`. That's why I used `xl5Arrows` to have 5 conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mark S. mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57183607/9290986), there is no default `xl5trafficlights` in the [`xlIconSet` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xliconset?view=excel-pia)

However, you are currently setting the `.Type`, `.Value` and `.Operator` of your IconCriteria - just makes sure to *also* set the `.Icon` at the same time.  This will set the `IconSetCriteria` to `xlCustomSet`.

This is an [`xlIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlicon?view=excel-pia) - the "circle" ones, for you to build your 5 traffic-light set from are as follows:

```
xlIconBlackCircleWithBorder
xlIconGrayCircle
xlIconGreenCircle
xlIconRedCircleWithBorder
xlIconPinkCircle
xlIconYellowCircle
xlIconGreenCheckSymbol
xlIconRedCrossSymbol
xlIconYellowExclamationSymbol
xlIconWhiteCircleAllWhiteQuarters
```

e.g.

```
    With .IconCriteria(1)
        .Icon = xlIconWhiteCircleAllWhiteQuarters
    End With
    With .IconCriteria(2)
        .Icon = xlIconGreenCircle
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 0.85
        .Operator = xlGreater
    End With
    With .IconCriteria(3)
        .Icon = xlIconYellowCircle
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 0.95
        .Operator = xlGreater
    End With
    With .IconCriteria(4)
        .Icon = xlIconRedCircleWithBorder
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 1.05
        .Operator = xlGreater
    End With
    With .IconCriteria(5)
        .Icon = xlIconBlackCircleWithBorder
        .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
        .Value = 1.15
        .Operator = xlGreater
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

However with the iconsets, I don't believe there is a format for 5 traffic light, only xl3TrafficLights1, xl4TrafficLights or xl3TrafficLights2. [You can read those here](https://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-apply-icon-set-conditional-formatting-with-vba-macro/)

Additionally, the component setting your criteria, based on what you said should be `.Operator = xlLess` or `.Operator =xlGreaterEqual`

1. value < 0.85 (xlLess)
2. value < 0.95 (xlLess)
3. value < 1.06 (xlLess)
4. value < 1.15 (xlLess)
5. value >=1.15 (xlGreaterEqual)

Comment: With `xl3trafficlights` you are forced to use either `xlGreatEqual` or `xlGreater`. So yes I agree that it should be
1. value >1.15
2. value > 1.06
3. value >0.95
4. value > 0.85
5. other value

As with conditions, the first condition is with other values, I do `ReverseOrder`

Comment: Is the Syntax `xlGreatEqual` or `xlGreaterEqual`? I'd like to make the adjustment

Comment: Thanks, @Arthur. I'll keep it as is then.